# Xamarin.Android - Permission denied emulator cannot be started

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I am very new to Xamarin.Android. When I run a project in Visual Studio 2015 it produces this error:

> 1>qemu-system-i386.exe: -drive
>   if=none,index=0,id=system,file=C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1/system-images\android-19\default\x86/system.img:
>   could not open disk image
>   C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1/system-images\android-19\default\x86/system.img:
>   Could not open
>   'C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1/system-images\android-19\default\x86/system.img':
>   Permission denied 1>Emulator AVD_for_Nexus_S cannot be started.

I thought it was HAXM, but that is installed. I feel it's something simple, but can't seem to find it.

Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 3):

Just grant full access permission to appropriate system.img file for all (or required only) users.

Comment: Worked Absolutely Fine.

Answer (score 2):

Run Visual Studio as Administrator.  In fact, I'd update your Visual Studio shortcut to always run Visual Studio as Administrator because this isn't the only case where you need Admin rights.

1. Right click on the shortcut and go to properties.
2. Click Advanced.
3. Click Run as administrator.
4. Click OK and OK.

Answer (score 1):

For not obvious reasons the Android emulator requests write-permissions to the system images. The emulator can't get these permissions without administrator rights because the image-files are located under *C:\Program Files*.

Move the SDK folder to a location where everyone has full access to (you can change the path Xamarin used in the options-dialog).

Comment: Hi Stefan thanks for the help! That fixed that the emulator launches (it doesn't do anything), however it now produces this:  
hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 8

Comment: Did you moved the SDK or did you grant permissions to the file? I am not sure if the second approach will work in every case. There are maybe some effects because the default path of the Android SDK has spaces.

Comment: I granted permission and the emulator launched, although it still hangs, I will try moving the location.

Comment: @RobD Now that you moved the files you might try and reinstall the emulator. They are always very flaky for me and get corrupted easily.

Comment: Thanks! Tried that, no \luck, finally gave up and switched to VS emulator. It seems to be working ok for now.